# I can't find configuration file of Wireshark on Centos7

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I installed the Wireshark on Centos7. But I can not find the configuration files. By default it should be in "/usr/local/share/Wireshark", but didn't it exist.

```
~[root@localhost share]# tshark -v
TShark 1.10.14 (Git Rev Unknown from unknown)

Copyright 1998-2015 Gerald Combs <gerald@wireshark.org> and contributors.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Compiled (64-bit) with GLib 2.54.2, with libpcap, with libz 1.2.7, with POSIX
capabilities (Linux), without libnl, with SMI 0.4.8, with c-ares 1.10.0, with
Lua 5.1, without Python, with GnuTLS 3.3.26, with Gcrypt 1.5.3, with MIT
Kerberos, without GeoIP.

Running on Linux 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64, with locale en_US.UTF-8, with libpcap
version 1.5.3, with libz 1.2.7.
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz

Built using gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36).

[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr/local/share/
[root@localhost share]# ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  28 Mar 14 16:39 applications
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   6 Apr 11  2018 info
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root root 243 Feb 11  2019 man
[root@localhost ~]# ll /etc/ | grep wireshark
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check where tshark config files are stored, use `tshark -G folders`. As an example, this is what I see on my system:

```sh
ubuntu$ tshark -G folders
Temp:                   /tmp
Personal configuration: /home/rj/.config/wireshark
Global configuration:   /usr/share/wireshark
System:                 /etc
Program:                /usr/bin
Personal Plugins:       /home/rj/.local/lib/wireshark/plugins/2.6
Global Plugins:         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wireshark/plugins/2.6
Personal Lua Plugins:   /home/rj/.local/lib/wireshark/plugins
Global Lua Plugins:     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wireshark/plugins
Extcap path:            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wireshark/extcap
MaxMind database path:  /usr/share/GeoIP
MaxMind database path:  /var/lib/GeoIP
MaxMind database path:  /usr/share/GeoIP
```

More information is available on using [wireshark configuration files](https://tshark.dev/packetcraft/arcana/profiles/) as well as [official docs](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAppFilesConfigurationSection.html), which detail the types.

Comment: thank you, I executed your advice and I seen the configuration files were in "/usr/share/Wireshark".